# Foreach only repeats last element

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-core

Trying to learn and integrate Knockout to an ASP.NET Core application. This is the farthest I have been able to get by following different posts:

```
function DayViewModel(number, name /*others*/)
{
    this.dayNumber = number;
    this.dayName = name;
    //others
}

var MonthViewModel = function(days /*others*/)
{
    this.monthDays = ko.observableArray(days);
}

$(function ()
{
    var tempDays = [];

    @foreach(var day in Model.Days)
    {
        string dayName = day.DayNumber.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + " - " + Globals.GetDayName(Model.YearNumber, Model.MonthNumber, day.DayNumber, Globals.GetUICulture(Context));
        @:tempDays.push(DayViewModel(@day.DayNumber, "@dayName" /*others*/);
    }

    var monthViewModel = new MonthViewModel(tempDays /*others*/);
    ko.applyBindings(monthViewModel);
});
```

Then, the table:

```
<table id="mTable" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => newModel.DayNumber)</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind="foreach: monthDays">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="#" data-bind="text: dayName"></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This correctly generates a `<tr>` element for the same number of items in the array, and the generated HTML shows me that `tempDays` has all the correct items.
Why does Knockout only repeat the last element then? What am I doing wrong that I cannot find in the documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to create a new instance of `MonthViewModel`, otherwise `this` would be overriden on every call, which makes the last `MonthViewModel` change everyone..

`@:tempDays.push(new DayViewModel(@day.DayNumber, "@dayName" /*others*/);`

Here is a fiddle without the Razor stuff: http://jsfiddle.net/LkqTU/32570/

Comment: Thanks so much, I feel like a noob. It worked perfectly

Answer (score -6):

use ng-repeat instead of foreach if your doing this in angularjs.
You will find ng-repeat example and syntax in w3school.

Comment: I am not using AngularJs, so ng-repeat is not available for me